# How to get the name of a foreign key in Django rest framework

Tags: django-rest-framework

Get the foreign key value of category instead of id when fetching data from pet Model with Django Rest Framework.  I am not sure where to put the Slug Related Field.

```
class PetSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    selected_category = serializers.SlugRelatedField(slug_field='selected_category',queryset=categoryType.objects.all())                                              
    class Meta:
        model = pet
        fields = '__all__'
```

Model

```
class pet(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    category = models.ForeignKey(
        "categoryType", on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, related_name='selected_category')

class categoryType(models.Model):
    categoryName = models.CharField(max_length=50)
```

Serializer

```
class PetSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = pet
        fields = '__all__'


class CategorySerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = categoryType
        fields = '__all__'
```

What i get if i do a get request

```
   {
        "id": 1,
        "title": "dog",
        "category": 2
    },
```

what i want to get

```
   {
        "id": 1,
        "title": "dog",
        "category": "Pet"
    },
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe two way you can achieve this.

#### First Possible Solution

You need to overwrite the `__str__()` method of `categoryType` and response your desire model_str() response, in this case which is `categoryName` name.

```py
class categoryType(models.Model):
    categoryName = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.categoryName
```

related [link](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/instances/#str)

#### Second Possible Solution

Another possible solution is to use [`serailizerMethodField`](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields/#serializermethodfield) and return your desire response for `category` field.

```py
class PetSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    category = serializers.SerializerMethodField()                                         
    class Meta:
        model = pet
        fields = ('id', 'title', 'category')
    def get_category(self, obj): 
        return obj.category.categoryName
```